# Multiply pages PHP - Problem

Tags: php, jquery, variables, post

I have a problem when creating a script. I have an index.php file, which controls all other pages. Though, I have a problem using the $_GET[''] with $_POST[''] variable in the pages.

I have a page, called **adpanel.php** Inside that page, I have use the $_GET function like this:

```
   if($_GET['newad'] == "create"):
    //In this, I only want the content showed when the above statement is true.
    endif;
```

The above code, does work. I do know how to show the content, if the $_GET is true. Although, inside the $_GET I have a $_POST function, which will submit through jquery, and return the data back to the adpanel.php page.

I have a problem, that it returns the full page in the status div. Example:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f8i95ba0

Below is my index, that controls the pages:

```
      case 'a': // Advertisement Panel
            if($_GET['newad']){
                if($_POST){
                include($settings['pagepath'].'adpanel.php&newad=create');
                }
                include($settings['pagepath'].'adpanel.php&newad=create');
            }
            if($_GET['manage']){ 
                getHeader();
                include($settings['pagepath'].'manageAds.php');
                getFooter();                            
            }else{
                getHeader();
                include($settings['pagepath'].'adpanel.php');
                getFooter();
            break;
            }
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Try using [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php). You switch could handle POST/GET at the same time without knowing which one was actually used. Not sure if this will fix your problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
case 'a': // Advertisement Panel
        if($_GET['newad']){
            if($_POST){
                include($settings['pagepath'].'adpanel.php&newad=create');
            }
            include($settings['pagepath'].'adpanel.php&newad=create');
        }
        if($_GET['manage']){ 
            getHeader();
            include($settings['pagepath'].'manageAds.php');
            getFooter();                            
        }else{
            getHeader();
            include($settings['pagepath'].'adpanel.php');
            getFooter();
            //break;<--remove break
        }
        break; //<-- break after if/else so it breaks on case and does not continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if(isset($_GET['manage'])){
```